# How to configure nginx for dynamic sub domain and handle reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I am using the following nginx settings:

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name localhost *.localhost ;


    access_log off;

    location /static/
   {
    autoindex on;
   alias /var/www/machax/static/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for ;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

But the problem with this is it is detecting the host as `127.0.0.1:8001` instead of `beta.localhost` or any other sub-domain. Just to test i tried hard coding the following as `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host beta.localhost ;` and that worked. Is there any way I can get the sub domain from append it dynamically to `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$host` [built in var](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) should contain the currently requested host. Try this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
```